# "Do you like my present" vs. "do you like your present"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, conversation, determiners

When my daughter received the present I bought to her, I asked her:

> Do you like my present?

Is this correct? Or I should say:

> Do you like your present?

Comment: Both versions are correct.  What's not correct is *I bought to her*  it should be *I bought **for** her*  Or, I suppose, *I **brought** to her*

Comment: Thx for the downvote. At least I got a hat

Comment: I'd go with "the present I bought her". We are not exactly writing a poem here.

Comment: [ell.se] is the best place for the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is suitable for ell.se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, it depends on the context of emphasis.  If you are specifically stressing that the gift came from you, "my gift" would make sense.

Also, "my gift" would still be appropriate if the gift has not yet been received or accepted.  Generally speaking, once a gift is given, at the time it is accepted, it stops being "my gift" and starts being "your gift".